# How to disable the shutdown/hibernate charge technology in my Asus laptop?

Tags: usb, motherboard, power-supply, power, asus-laptop

My Asus laptop with windows 7 has a very persistent sleep charge technology (it keeps the power on even after the computer shutdown). How can I disable this feature? I don't see anything related to that in the bios.

I have also tried setting the Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power option in the USB Root Hubs' Properties in Device Manager and enabling USB selective suspend in power options - it didn't work.

Comment: That doesn't happen on my laptops! What OS are you running? Have you checked the power management settings? If Windows, as a quick test, set your power policy to "High performance" and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: I'll check them now. - my laptop is an asus notebook, running windows 7

Comment: I checked it... and the USB selective suspension was activated for both on battery and on power supply. So it must not be that setting. I'm thinking I may have better odds with the motherboard definitions. (I'll have to shutdown and restart in order to check them)

Comment: Ok, all checked. No BIOS options to turn this feature off. I think I'm out of luck this time.

Comment: Try turning the USB selective suspension _off_.

Comment: That was what I checked upon your first comment. Unfortunately it did not work...

Comment: Yes. I'm suggesting that you turn it off. i.e. not-active for both battery and on AC.

Comment: I did, it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I couldn't understand clearly what you meant but I guess you mean when your computer is shutdown.
Naturally, computers cutoff power being sent to USB ports when it is shutdown or hibernated and in some cases, in sleep mode EXCEPT in certain computers with special features like the *SLEEP CHARGE TECHNOLOGY* which allows specified USB port(s) to be powered while in sleep mode, shutdown or hibernated.
The *SLEEP CHARGE TECHNOLOGY* can be configured in either the BIOS setting or in the computer manufacturer's settings software.
You should also try out those options or elucidate more.

Comment: I think you understood it perfectly (I appear to lack the vocabulary to describe the problem adequately...).

Comment: My laptop seems to have Sleep Charge Technology and what I want to do is to disable that feature. But I can't find any options in the bios related to the sleep charge.

Comment: I edited the question to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: Then use the manufacturer's settings software.

Comment: I have a Asus PC Suite disk. I'll check if it has anything useful.

Comment: I thought I had one... But I was mistaking if for an LG PC Suite Disk, which is not for this computer. Meanwhile I've contacted the ASUS support so that they may give me some insight on this matter.

Comment: Okay. Some laptops does not have the option in the bios, it's most likely to be found on the Asus' system setting when you've booted into your OS. Look around for it to see if you can find something like that. 
Also, I wish you luck with Asus support to help us solve one problem at hand.

Comment: I found something this evening and it's called Asus usb charger+. You can check it out on the web and let me know what you think about it. Here's a link to make your search easier  http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/ASUS-USB-Charger-Plus-10210-program.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can disable hibernate by running `powercfg.exe /hibernate off` *as admin*. This will disable it completely (and remove the option from power settings windows as well) until you turn it back on with the same command (replacing 'off' with 'on').

`powerconfig/h off` in Windows 10 for those curious.

Comment: At least, this is the solution to the problem you pose _as I interpreted it_.

Hibernation is generally what keeps your system running even when it is turned off; this is more than likely how Asus is able to run Smart Charge when the system  has already been shutdown. Run the command, reboot, test your situation again. If it doesn't work, well, run the command again and turn it back on, move along to the next troubleshoot!

Comment: it has been some time since I posted this thread. It brings back memories. In any case, I came to the conclusion that this bios does not allow for the power to the USB to be controlled programmatically (it's always on unless the computer is both off and disconnected from the external power source). There really was no way around it.

Comment: PS: that was a somewhat old notebook (bought in 2008, made a year and a half  or 2 years earlier, so... 10 year old tech essentially, no smart charge included in that model - is now running windows 10. lmao. Asus has some good stuff, never had a single issue with any of their products).

Comment: Tell me about it; I have one from '09, 11in with an i3, and it _still_ runs like a champ. Thank you for responding with your finding - even if it was an old question - now I have another tidbit for future reference.